# Is there a Linq function that returns indices?

Tags: c#, linq

Basically, the equivalent of this:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> Enumerate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    int i = 0;
    return enumerable.Select(e => new KeyValuePair<int, T>(i++, e));
}
```

Python has one, but I can't find it in C#. If not, no biggie, I just wrote it, but if it already exists, I'd rather stick to the standard. Beats having an akward `int i=0` declaration above each `foreach`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return enumerable.Select((e, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, T>(i, e));
```

Also note that your approach using `i++` as a captured variable is not safe; someone could call `Count()` first, for example - of use `Parallel`.

Comment: @Ahmad: I was going to up-vote you too, but you deleted it already. I don't think he deserves extra cred because he beat you to the punch-line ;)

Comment: I guess I could use this in-place too, instead of foreach? `myEnum.Select((e, i) => { /* my loop contents */ });` ?

Comment: @Mark - well, LINQ uses deferred execution - so by itself a `Select` does very little. It probably doesn't replace `foreach` in most scenarios.

Comment: @Marc: Oh...right. Didn't think that through. I know `ToList()` and other methods will execute/evaluate the expression...but is there a method specifically for that? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: @Mark - not really. `Count()` would do it, but it isn't logically clear what you are trying to do. I'd stick with `foreach` if you just want to do something for each item. Maybe `Parallel.ForEach` if you feel exotic.